# after upgrading to xcode 6, OpenGLES/gltypes.h not found

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es, ios8

I'm having an issue compiling my iOS code which was building with the earlier version of XCode.

I import UIKit/UIKit.h in my prefix header file, which with iOS 8 SDK cascades down to including CoreVideo/CVOpenGLESTexture.h, and from there OpenGLES/gltypes.h. In the preprocessor stage, XCode complains that the file gltypes.h is not found.

In the Search Paths for the Target, I've ensured that the Framework Search Paths and Header Search Paths are pointing to the location of the SDK installation.  Also, "Always Search User Paths" is set to Yes.

Anyone else seen this issue? "Linked Framework and Libraries" has OpenGLES.framework above "CoreVideo.framework" or any other linked frameworks.

**Update**
XCode 6 was installed as an update from App Store.  Also tried uninstalling XCode (by dragging app to trash), and re-installing from App Store.  Did not help.

**Update**
I removed the prefix header file, and set "Precompile Prefix Header" to "No", deleted the cache where xcode would place the precompiled information.  Still no give.

Now where ever UIKit/UIKit.h is imported, this error is thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what I did to get over this:

1. Quit XCode
2. Removed all reference to OpenGLES.framework from the .xcodeproj file
3. Restarted XCode, and opened the project
4. Deleted all derived data (Windows->Organizer->Projects->Derived
   Data->Delete)
5. Let XCode re-index

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked some time ago, but I just had the same problem and fixed it.

I was working on an iOS app I inherited, and somehow they added the OpenGLES framework to the root of their source folder, and it was that version of OpenGLES framework that they added to the project as a linked framework instead of the one provided by the SDK.

So I removed that from the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries", and added the one supplied by the SDK. Stopped getting that error after doing so.